# Set background color vuetify textfield

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I have  a codepen https://codepen.io/handy29/pen/yLLwjGg and I want to that textfield have background color #EAEAEA. But as you can see in my codepen, there is a little white color, and my question how to replace this little white color to #EAEAEA? I think I can use inset background color like:

```
#padding-phone .v-input__slot {
    /* background: #EAEAEA; */
    --padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 var(--padding) #EAEAEA;
  }
  #padding-phone .v-text-field__slot {
    background: #EAEAEA;
  }
```

and it didn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using background color instead of box-shadow? It seems to work fine on your codepen

```
#padding-phone .v-input__slot {
   --padding: 10px;
   background: #EAEAEA !important;
}
#padding-phone .v-text-field__slot {
   background: #EAEAEA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust your css tag to

```
  #padding-phone .v-text-field__slot {
background-color: #EAEAEA;
}
```